# How to call the defaults method of parent model in backbone

Tags: javascript, inheritance, backbone.js, superclass

I have created a ParentModel and few other models which extend ParentModel. Each ChildModel has some additional properties than ParentModel.

I want to call defaults method of ParentModel and get that JSON and add some additional properties and return the modified object from the defaults of ChildModel.

Here is my code:

```
var ParentModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  defaults: function() {
    return {
      name: '',
      description: '',
      ruleType: '',
      creationDate: ''
    };
  }
});

var ChildModel = ParentModel.extend({
  defaults: function() {
    //Q: How to get the defaults from ParentModel and add one more property to json
  }
});

var c = new ChildModel({});
```

But I am unable to figure out **How to call the defaults method of the class it is extending (ParentModel)** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

_.extend({extraProps:here}, ParentModel.prototype.defaults)

Comment: Thank you @Robert for quick answer (+1). But why we have to use ParentModel word in the defaults method. Shouldn't something look like this: this.parent.prototype.defaults or this.superClass.prototype.defaults ?

Comment: Moreover, isn't your answer should be this `_.extend(ParentModel.prototype.defaults(), {extraProps:here})`. Two things: Call the defaults method and it should be first argument.

Comment: JS has no concept of parent classes sp you have to do it this way.  Extend modifies the object you pass in the first param so you don't want to pass the parent's defaults there.  You could pass {} as the first param, then then the parent, then the subclass though

Comment: Oh..I didn't know about that. Thanks for this useful information.

Answer (score 1):

Backbone lets you access the prototype of the parent through the `__super__` property.

So you can call a parent method like this:

```
this.constructor.__super__.parentMethod.apply( this, arguments )
```

So in your case:

```
var ChildModel = ParentModel.extend({
    defaults: function() {
        return _.extend( 
            { extraProps: 'here' }, 
            this.constructor.__super__.defaults.apply( this, arguments )
        );
    }
});
```

Explanation:

- `__super__` is a "static" property, not a prototype property, so it must be accessed through `this.constructor.__super__` instead of just `this.__super__`.
- We use [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FFunction%2Fapply) here instead of just calling `defaults()` directly. This allows us to do two things. First, it lets us set the value that `this` will have inside of the parent `defaults()` method. That isn't important in your case, but it can be when other parent methods are being overridden. Then we use the second argument of `apply()` to pass along any `arguments` that were passed to the child function. Again, this is not important in your case, but may be useful for others.